# setInterval stops without any reason when browser tab is background

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

I am working on an application that sends current timestamp to database every 2 minutes with AJAX using setInterval.

But somehow setInterval stops after some minutes (i didnt calculate the exact time), but i believe it happens when i dont open that browser's tab for 20-30 minutes.

```
function tmstmp() {
$.post("send_functions.php?act=time");
}

$(function() { 
setInterval(tmstmp, 60000);
});
```

Is that normal that setInterval stops if that tab is not on foreground ?

If yes, how can i prevent setInterval to stop ? or check if it stopped ?

Thanks

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951727/setinterval-not-working-properly-on-chrome

Comment: Check my edited answer. Should at least give you a clue if the interval works.

Comment: @amnotiam You can't make comments wiki!!!

Comment: BTW, why would you want to send timestamps to your web server? I am sure that there is a way for your web server to acquire the exact timestamp data you are trying to send it with every POST request.

Comment: i am sending it to mysql to "last_access" row to check if user still online.

Comment: @gdoron: Very true. Of course there's no rep for comments, so I'm fine with that... for now.

Comment: @amnotiam. You gave me an idea for a new question in `Meta` LOL...

Comment: This might be a more useful example to work with (with how I would do it with `setTimeout()` instead): http://jsfiddle.net/kxa53/

Answer (score 2):

You should try to make an function call on page startup:

```
test();
```

and then loop that function:

```
function test() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // your code
        test();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not supposed to happen.
Browsers may indeed reduce the timer resolution to something around 1/s, but not clear the setInterval.

Could there be some bug in your code that causes a `clearInterval`?

Comment: no there is no bug as i added to code here. when i did search on google i saw that many ppl face this issue.

Comment: Hm, I never heard of that issue. Can you cite some sources?

Comment: for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203304/setinterval-stops-after-ajax-request

Answer (score -1):

No code + no debug information = hard to tell what went wrong.

Just to be sure add the following line to the code (method) that gets executed with `setInterval` and watch after 20-30 minutes if you still get output in the console.

```
console.log('Yep! I am alive!');
```

**EDIT:** Could be anything but try changing the **tmstmp** method to include a callback function after the POST request gets executed. That way you'll at least know that it works.

```
function tmstmp() {
    $.post("send_functions.php?act=time", function(data){
        console.log('Yep! I am alive!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Well... If you had the code, would you spend the time debugging it- meaning wait couple of times 20-30 minutes? **:)**

Comment: @gdoron just change the interval time to a few seconds while you're debugging.

Comment: will try and write here thx. by the way should i use setTimeout with repeated function ? is it better than setInterval ?

Comment: Generally `setTimeout()` has proven to be much more reliable than `setInterval()`.

Comment: @holodoc - I prefer `setTimeout()` to `setInterval()` in many cases where they may both work, but with a 60 second interval, I don't know the statement that one is more or less reliable is accurate.