# Asp .Net MVC5 application doesn't send ajax request in setInterval method

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I tried to send ajax post request in MVC5 application in setInterval, but it sends the request only when page is in focus. How do I send the request even when page is not in focus.

```
 function sendData() { 
var location = {coords :{longitude : "long", latitude: "latt"}};
var locData = { Longitude: location.coords.longitude, Lattitude: location.coords.latitude }

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/values/",
    data: locData,
    success : function(){ console.log("msg sent success")}
})

}

setInterval(sendData, 60000);
```

Comment: Did u wrapped the code with 

`$(document).ready(function()
{

});`

Comment: You can't be showing us the full code here. None of what you have showed is affected by whether the page is in view or not.

Comment: @DavidG Believe it or not but I am getting the problem :) I guess the problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203304/setinterval-stops-after-ajax-request?rq=1
Tried this as well but same issue...

Answer (score 0):

You may use this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setInterval(function () {

    //--------Start of Code--------//  

    //---------End of Code--------//

    }, 60000);
});
```

Also, I notice that you are not passing the **location** parameter to `SendData` function.

Comment: I have tried wrapping the function in document.ready but still the function sendData gets hit only when the tab in which page is open is active!!

Also , I have updated the method where location parameter was missed.